# NetSuite - Using SuiteScript to Create Button to Print Packing List on Transfer Order

Tags: forms, printing, transactions, netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to follow SuiteAnswers 41269 (which is for adding a Packing List to an Item Fulfillment) to add a button to print a packing list to a Transfer Order. This is essentially a test to try and be able to print more forms on more transactions that aren't native to NetSuite (VRMAs, etc.).

Note that the SuiteAnswers above seems to be out of date, because it references SS1.0 and SS2.0, but some of the code for SS2.0 also appears to use SS1.0 code.  Since that SA was a little off, I've gone through a lot of the NetSuite help files on the different parts of the render and url modules to help build out these scripts.

My issue is that I keep getting thrown back an error when the "Print 1" button is clicked:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: print1 is not defined
    at trnfrord.nl?id=658266&whence=&cmid=1652279684591_1868:1132:30
    at Object.execCb (NsRequire.js:2047:26)
    at Ma.check (NsRequire.js:1193:28)
    at Ma.enable (NsRequire.js:1475:10)
    at Ma.init (NsRequire.js:1106:11)
    at NsRequire.js:1771:18
```

I'm using a UserEvent Script, a Client Script, and a Suitelet Script.  I'm currently using a static entity ID of the Transfer Order while I'm testing this, and will add a dynamic one once I get this working.

**UPDATE:**
After taking in the suggestion below, I realized I had the deploymentID set to the actual internal ID of the deployment, not the ID that matched the scriptID field. I also realized my beforeLoad function was using scriptContext instead of context, which was inside the function.

After fixing these issues, I started getting a "You are not allowed to navigate directly to this page" error. My script deployments were set to testing, so I changed them to released, and I still got this error.

I changed the returnExternalUrl from true to false and received an "Invalid PDF Layout" error.

I looked online and realized that part of my mistake was using the formID of the actual PDF, not create a new Custom Transaction Form and assign the PDF to print from that form.

Having done that, I am now receiving this error:

```
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":null,"stack":["renderPackingSlip(N/render)","onRequest(/SuiteScripts/buttonTest2/print_suitelet_script.js:18)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","details":null,"userEvent":null,"stackTrace":["renderPackingSlip(N/render)","onRequest(/SuiteScripts/buttonTest2/print_suitelet_script.js:18)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"7fb1b24b-b66f-44bf-b6f3-282444013ca5-2d323032322e30352e3133","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":false}
```

Here are the the updated scripts as they stand now, which throw the above error:

**UPDATED UE SCRIPT:**

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define([
    'N/url',
    'N/ui/serverWidget',
],

    function (url) {

        function beforeLoad(scriptContext) {

            try {
                if (scriptContext.type == 'view') {
                    const href = url.resolveScript({
                        scriptId: 699,
                        deploymentId: 3,
                        returnExternalUrl: true
                    });
                    scriptContext.form.addButton({
                        id: 'custpage_print1',
                        label: 'Print 1',
                        functionName: "(window.location='" + href + "')"
                    });

                }
            } catch (error) {
                log.debug('ERROR', error);
            }
        }

        return {
            beforeLoad: beforeLoad
        };

    });
```

**UPDATED SS SCRIPT:**

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */

 define(['N/render'],

 function(render) {

     function onRequest(context) {
     
       var total = 0;

          if (context.request.method == 'GET'){

         var ifid = context.request.parameters.custparam_ifid;

           var fileObj = render.packingSlip({
                    entityId: 658266,
                    printMode: render.PrintMode.PDF,
                    formId: 129
             });

                 fileObj.save()
          }
     }

     return {

         onRequest: onRequest
     };

  });
```

**PDF:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
<pdf>
<head>
    <link name="NotoSans" type="font" subtype="truetype" src="${nsfont.NotoSans_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSans_Bold}" src-italic="${nsfont.NotoSans_Italic}" src-bolditalic="${nsfont.NotoSans_BoldItalic}" bytes="2" />
    <#if .locale == "zh_CN">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKsc" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKsc_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKsc_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "zh_TW">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKtc" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKtc_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKtc_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "ja_JP">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKjp" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKjp_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKjp_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "ko_KR">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKkr" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKkr_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKkr_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "th_TH">
        <link name="NotoSansThai" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansThai_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansThai_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    </#if>
    <macrolist>
        <macro id="nlheader">
            <table style="width: 100%; font-size: 10pt;"><tr>
    <td rowspan="3" style="padding: 0px; width: 222px;"><#if companyInformation.logoUrl?length != 0><img src="${companyInformation.logoUrl}" style="margin: 5px; width: 120px; height: 60px; float: left;" /> </#if></td>
    <td rowspan="3" style="padding: 0px; width: 248px;">${companyInformation.addressText}</td>
    <td align="right" style="padding: 0px; width: 323px;"><span style="font-size: 28pt;">${record@title}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" style="width: 337px;"><span class="number">#${record.tranid}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" style="width: 337px;">${record.trandate}</td>
    </tr></table>
        </macro>
        <macro id="nlfooter">
            <table class="footer"><tr><#if preferences.PRINT_BARCODES>
    <td><barcode codetype="code128" showtext="true" value="${record.tranid}"/></td>
    </#if>
    <td align="right"><pagenumber/> of <totalpages/></td>
    </tr></table>
        </macro>
    </macrolist>
    <style type="text/css">* {
        <#if .locale == "zh_CN">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKsc, sans-serif;
        <#elseif .locale == "zh_TW">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKtc, sans-serif;
        <#elseif .locale == "ja_JP">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKjp, sans-serif;
        <#elseif .locale == "ko_KR">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKkr, sans-serif;
        <#elseif .locale == "th_TH">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansThai, sans-serif;
        <#else>
            font-family: NotoSans, sans-serif;
        </#if>
        }
        table {
            font-size: 9pt;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
        th {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 8pt;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding: 5px 6px 3px;
            background-color: #e3e3e3;
            color: #333333;
        }
        td {
            padding: 4px 6px;
        }
        td p { align:left }
        b {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #333333;
        }
        table.header td {
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        table.footer td {
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 8pt;
        }
        table.itemtable th {
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }
        table.body td {
            padding-top: 2px;
        }
        td.addressheader {
            font-size: 8pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding-top: 6px;
            padding-bottom: 2px;
        }
        td.address {
            padding-top: 0;
        }
        span.title {
            font-size: 28pt;
        }
        span.number {
            font-size: 16pt;
        }
        span.itemname {
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 150%;
        }
        div.returnform {
            width: 100%;
            /* To ensure minimal height of return form */
            height: 200pt;
            page-break-inside: avoid;
            page-break-after: avoid;
        }
        hr {
            border-top: 1px dashed #d3d3d3;
            width: 100%;
            color: #ffffff;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            height: 1px;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body header="nlheader" header-height="10%" footer="nlfooter" footer-height="20pt" padding="0.5in 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in" size="Letter">
    <table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr></table>

<table class="body" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><tr>
    <th style="width: 160px;">${record.shipmethod@label}</th>
    <th>${record.shipphone@label}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 160px;">${record.shipmethod}</td>
    <td>${record.shipphone}</td>
    </tr></table>
<#if record.item?has_content>

<table class="itemtable" style="margin-top:10px;width:100%;">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="12" style="width: 264px;">Item</th>
    <th colspan="4" style="width: 165px;">UPC / ISBN</th>
    <th colspan="3" style="width: 90px;">Options</th>
    <th colspan="3" style="width: 90px;">Retail</th>
    <th align="right" colspan="2" style="width: 89px;">Remaining</th>
    <th align="right" colspan="2" style="width: 64px;">Shipped</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<#list record.item as tranline><tr>
    <td colspan="12" style="width: 264px;"><span style="font-size:11px;"><span class="itemname">${tranline.item}</span></span><br /><span style="font-size:10px;">${tranline.description}</span></td>
    <td colspan="4" style="width: 165px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${tranline.custcol_nsts_csic_upc}</span></td>
    <td colspan="3" style="width: 90px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${tranline.options} <#if (tranline.custcol_nsts_csre_rnt_guid?has_content)> Rental <#else> </#if> </span></td>
    <td colspan="3" style="width: 90px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${tranline.custcol_retail}</span></td>
    <td align="right" colspan="2" style="width: 89px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${tranline.quantityremaining}</span></td>
    <td align="right" colspan="2" style="width: 64px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${tranline.quantity}</span></td>
    </tr>
    </#list></table>
&nbsp;

<table align="right" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:35%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 114px;">Quantity Total</td>
    <td style="width: 97px;">${record.quantity.total}</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 114px;">Subtotal</td>
    <td style="width: 97px;">${record.custbody_pack_slip_subtotal}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 114px;">Shipping &amp; Handling</td>
    <td style="width: 97px;">${record.custbody_pack_slip_shiptotal}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 114px;">Tax</td>
    <td style="width: 97px;">${record.custbody_pack_slip_taxtotal}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 114px;">Total</td>
    <td style="width: 97px;">${record.custbody_pack_slip_trxtotal}</td>
    </tr></table>
</#if>
</body>
</pdf>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know Suite Answer suggests this but there is an alternate solution that lets you skip the Client Script , by directly redirecting from the button to the Suitelet by directly putting the redirection on the button.  The inside of your event script beforeLoad function would look like this

```
const href = url.resolveScript({
                    scriptId:698,
                    deploymentId:  1695,
                    returnExternalUrl: true
            });

context.form.addButton({
                    id:'custpage_print1',
                    label: 'Print 1',
                    functionName: "(window.location='"+href +"')"
            });
```

Don't forget to load the N/url module

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm editing my post with the updated UE script at the bottom. It now removes the print button from the transfer order, so I've clearly done something incorrect (the UE is deployed to the Transfer Order).

One thing your comment made me realize was that on my original client script the scriptID and deploymentID were pointing at the UE script not the suitescript. I changed it on my original version, and was still receiving the same error.

Comment: you need to add url as function parameter in your UserEvent script to be able to call it as weel as add the N/ui/serverWidget one I believe.

Comment: Getting much closer!  I have a new error message, with the updated scripts (in my edit):
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":null,"stack":["renderPackingSlip(N/render)","onRequest(/SuiteScripts/buttonTest2/print_suitelet_script.js:18)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","details":null,"userEvent":null,"stackTrace":["renderPackingSlip(N/render)","onRequest(/SuiteScripts/buttonTest2/print_suitelet_script.js:18)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"7fb1b24b-b66f-44bf-b6f3-282444013ca5-2d323032322e30352e3133","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":false}

Comment: there is an error in your pdf template. Are you managing to generate it by hand?

Comment: In trying to test if it will generate manually, I'm going to this address: https://[ACCOUNT]-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/accounting/print/hotprint.nl?regular=T&sethotprinter=T&formnumber=182&trantype=TrnfrOrd&id=658266 - Would that be the right place to go?

I'm going to edit the original post with my PDF as it stands now.  My concern is that it isn't properly pulling information from the transfer order and that's generating the error. If I try to do transferorder.item, for instance, it throws an error in the PDF template editor

Comment: I've done more testing and tweaking and am still getting the same error.  At one point, my PDF template only read:
<pdf>
<body>
${record.tranid}
</body>
</pdf>

And it was still throwing the same error as above.

Comment: One thing I have tried is to switch over to a Picking Ticket instead of Packing Slip, and in doing that I'm able to generate a blank page from the PDF, but no actual code but no error.

`/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */
 define(['N/render'],

 function(render) {
     function onRequest(context) {
           var fileObj = render.pickingTicket({
                    entityId: 658266,
                    printMode: render.PrintMode.PDF,
                    formId: 176
             });
     }
     return {
         onRequest: onRequest
     };
  });`

Comment: Ok new update - I was able to print my test picking ticket by entering it manually (there was a settings in preferences preventing me from seeing it).  However, my print button is still displaying just a blank page, so there is some disconnect between the two.

Comment: I think my issue is arising from NetSuite being unable to generate  a Packing Slip for a Transfer Order if it hasn't been fulfilled yet.  I think I may have to see if I can build one myself by writing out the xml info in SS instead of the PDF templates

Answer (score 0):

You are not invoking the function or providing an eval argument (sort of). The functionName argument should just be the exported function name from the client script without parens. e.g.:

```js
functionName: 'print1'
```

Also note that the client script doesn't have to be a ClientScript and that (IMO) your code is more portable if you use

```js
 formObj.clientScriptModulePath = './custom_print_CS.js'; // or whatever you name it and save it besid your User Event script code.
```

and your client script could look like:

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 */

define([
    'N/url',
],

function(url) {


    function print1() {
        var output = url.resolveScript({
            scriptId: 698,
            deploymentId: 1695,
            returnExternalUrl: true
        });
       
        window.open(output);
   }
   
   return {
        print1: print1
   };
})
```

Comment: Thanks for looking!

I did as you suggested, and am getting different errors (which is always an improvement, right?)

I'm updating the original question with the new errors

Comment: You might want to also update the question with the user event and client script changes otherwise there's nothing really to comment on

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the scripts in the post now.

I did have to leave in the ScriptType and pageInit functions in ClientScript because NetSuite was throwing an error without them.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: For a script loaded from the user event you don’t ( or at least didn’t always ) have to register it as a Client Script.

Comment: Also you missed out the `form.clientScriptModulePath` call to pull in the page script